# Undefined Index line 40 filling up my log file

Tags: php, logging, undefined, notice

This line is causing my log files to fill with Undefined Index

```
$calculated[$tag_id] > 0 ? $calculated[$tag_id] = $calculated[$tag_id]+1 : $calculated[$tag_id] = 1;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make the ternary operation equal to a variable , instead of setting the array key in the operation

`$calculated[$tag_id] = ($calculated[$tag_id] > 0) ? $calculated[$tag_id] + 1 : 1;`